Visual Studio giving 'does not implement interface member error' when pull from Git
We are using Visual Studio 17.9.6
When I pull from Git I get multiple errors like this for changed files:

'ExampleRepo' does not implement interface member 'IExampleRepo.Add()'

However, as soon as I open the file IExampleRepo.cs and the references have finished loading, the error goes away.
Rebuilding the solution does not fix this issue until I have manually opened each affected file.
This issue started happening in the last 1-2 months across all our developers.
Has anyone experienced this and know of a fix?

did someone change that interface? are there a lot of changes that the compiler/tooling has to understand? if its just ephemeral thing, I wouldn't worry about it

Yes, minimal changes to the affected files. This issue happens several times a week. Had hoped it was a temporary VS bug but it's been going on too long now.

its sounding like not a bug, but a race between the compiler and git changing the file system
